# Unity Glitching when I run the Game

Tags: unity-game-engine

I made a Model of the solar system and when I run the program this happens:
[image: This is the Image]

I am not sure what is causing this so if you have any idea Pls Reply.

Comment: Reply Soon Pls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Scene load is being triggered multiple times:

Check if you have any code that you're using to load the scene (In Update, perhaps?) if youre using it in update, check if you're using GetKey instead of GetKeyDown (GetKey will remain true as long as you keep it pressed)

The information provided here is too little and we can only speculate at this point. please post code, more images and a better description of the problem. How did you reproduce this issue?

Comment: ok thanks for the advice in fact you were right the scene load was in update and it kept loading a scene as long as a value was true so this happened.Thank you for the answer

Comment: no problem! do Mark it as an accepted answer if it helped! :)